# Unable to display JavaScript widget

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a JustGiving widget to my website but it doesn't display at all. I had other scripts in the file which I thought might be interfering so I ended up testing in a new plain html file and it still wouldn't work.

Interestingly enough if I copy/paste it into a W3 schools code editor it works! It's the same exact code and I cannot work out why it doesn't load in an html file.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="jg-charity-events-board" data-config="id=45107">123</div>
      <script>
        (function(d) {
          var jg = d.createElement('script');
          jg.type = 'text/javascript';
          jg.async = true;
          jg.src = (d.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://widgets.justgiving.com/charity-events-board/host.js' : 'http://widgets.justgiving.com/charity-events-board/host.js');
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(jg, s);
        })(document);
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: any errors in your browser's Console?

Comment: Is it case where your document doesn't have script tag on a page, there for selector can't resolve where to put it?
"document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]" == undefined ?

Comment: @Raimonds surely the `<script>` tag which contains the code above would be selected, no?

Comment: try disabling you Ad blocking extension? When I tried your code in jsFiddle after disabling Ad block, it worked. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh2L3z4p/)

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: I've disabled all extensions and tried Firefox, IE, Chrome. I will try a different workstation also to verify this.

Comment: You might also want to try out applying https from where you're testing.

Comment: @ADyson No because that script tag is not yet injected into dom, what script does, it tries to find any existing script tags on your page and inject newly created one right after it. If there is no script tags when this bit of code is running it won't insert anything, that would be my guess. its easy to test, just amend script code so it console.log value of your target before it tries to insert it. if it is undefined this is your issue.

Comment: @Raimonds _"No because that script tag is not yet injected into dom"_ ...if the script is being executed, then it must have already been injected into the DOM and into the page. I just tested it and I'm right. Create a blank file and paste `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          console.log(s);
</script>
</body>
</html>` into it. Open it in the browser and check the console. You'll see it logs the script tag. JS code can't be executed unless it's in the DOM

Comment: Oh right I forgot it's inline tag, for me it disconnected into embed file, you can check network tab then, maybe request is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you just not use something like this? Didn't test but I assume it works.

```
<div id="scripts"></div>
<script>
    var url = document.location.protocol + '//widgets.justgiving.com/charity-events-board/host.js';
    var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="${url}"></script>';
    document.getElementById("scripts").innerHTML = script;
</script>
```

And jQuery has html and append functions for this.

Comment: I get a blank documents with:
'; document.getElementById("scripts").innerHTML = script;

Comment: Did you try to print what happens? alert("test"), console.log("test")? Also try to inspect the page and view the page source. Try in different browsers.